# c++ function invocation listener

Tags: c#, c++

I have a code written in c++ and it's a windows application.

i would like to leave the code as is and create another project (C# or C++ - rather C#)

that will "listen" to some functions invocations in that windows application.

I don't know where even to begin, can it be only dll or must be executable or even how to hook up the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your C++ library in managed mode, and then you can use the .dll into your c# project.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into another application with the help of WinAPI, so your program doesn't need to be a DLL but, I think it won't allow for you to listen for the calls to the functions etc. You should have some sort of a "signaller" in the original process which you can capture at the hooking one...

This is logical when you see this case as well: the compiler, due to the optimisations and such, sometimes replaces the inline functions with their bare specializations; thus removing the branching completely. Now, in this case, how can you know if a branching occured, right?..

Maybe, instead of hooking, you might change the design pattern - you might change the projects (if you can, of course) and make them two processes messaging with each other. This can be done using APIs and such - which would make your programs OS specific - but this would be like rewriting some parts of the application (main one) completely.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I can't change the original application, since it were already delivered to the customers. Need to figure out a way to do so without.